How to get absolute position (coordinates) of a figure in LaTeX?
I'm trying to determine the absolute position of figures in my LaTeX document. Specifically, I need to get the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of each figure.
I've heard that the zref package might be helpful, particularly its \zsavepos, \zposx, and \zposy commands. However, I'm struggling to implement this correctly.
Here's what I've tried so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \zsavepos{fig-start}
    \centering
    \rule{100pt}{100pt} % A simple 100x100pt black square for testing
    \caption{A test figure}
    \zsavepos{fig-end}
\end{figure}

Top-left: (\zposx{fig-start}, \zposy{fig-start})
Bottom-right: (\zposx{fig-end}, \zposy{fig-end})

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[red] 
        (\zposx{fig-start}sp, -\zposy{fig-start}sp) rectangle 
        (\zposx{fig-end}sp, -\zposy{fig-end}sp);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

This compiles, and the coordinates I obtain are "Top-left: (8799518, 43889459) Bottom-right: (8799518, 35766636)". But I don't see the tikz rectangle on my document. I'm not sure if the positions it's giving me are correct or how to interpret them.
Note that this is just a toy example and what I'm really trying to achieve here is an automatic way of logging all figure coordinates to a .txt file during the complication process, so I'm open to other different solutions.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

The units are sp.  Since you are usually at the top or bottom of a column, you could use a tikzmark and tikzpagenodes to get relative positions.  Note that you may be getting the location of the current baseline, which is below the top (see \topskip and \partopsep.).

Also, zref origin (lower left corner) may not be the same as the TeX origin.  Loading geometry will fix that.
